# How can I destroy particles on collision with specific a GameObject?

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection, particles

I wrote a script to manage my Particle System emission. The starting lifespan is set to infinite so that the particle never dies until it reaches a specific collider. I didn't find any method to destroy a specific particle in the Unity Manual.

How can I do this?

Here's the code (updated to show the partial fix)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class PlayerDamage : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ParticleSystem ps;
    public List<ParticleCollisionEvent> collisionEvents;
    public int attackValue = 1;

    //
    [Range(0.0f, 100f)]
    public int maxParticles;
    public float particleLife;
    public bool neverDies;
    public float particleSpeed = 8.0F;


    void Start()
    {
        ps = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        collisionEvents = new List<ParticleCollisionEvent>();
        //
        var collision = ps.collision;
        collision.enabled = true;
        collision.type = ParticleSystemCollisionType.World;
        collision.mode = ParticleSystemCollisionMode.Collision3D;
    }

    void OnParticleCollision(GameObject other)
    {
        int numCollisionEvents = ps.GetCollisionEvents(other, collisionEvents);

        Rigidbody rb = other.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        int i = 0;

        while (i < numCollisionEvents)
        {
            if (rb.CompareTag("Enemy"))
            {
                BaseHealth baseHealth = other.GetComponent<BaseHealth>();

                if (baseHealth != null)
                {
                    Vector3 pos = collisionEvents[i].intersection;
                    Vector3 force = collisionEvents[i].velocity;// * 10;
                    rb.AddForce(force);
                    baseHealth.TakeDamage(attackValue);
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var collision = ps.collision;
        collision.maxKillSpeed = particleSpeed;

        Debug.Log("Particles Alive Count: " + GetAliveParticles());

        ps.Emit(maxParticles);
        var main = ps.main;
        main.maxParticles = Mathf.RoundToInt(maxParticles);
        main.startLifetime = particleLife;

        if (neverDies)
        {
            particleLife = float.PositiveInfinity;
        }
        else
        {
            particleLife = 5f;
        }
    }



    int GetAliveParticles()
    {
        ParticleSystem.Particle[] particles = new ParticleSystem.Particle[ps.particleCount];
        return ps.GetParticles(particles);
    }
}
```

Comment: Taking a look at the API, it doesn't look like there's an efficient way to do this. You'd need to iterate over the whole list of particles, comparing their positions to find the ones that struck this particular object. Can you tell us more about the effect you're trying to achieve? There might be simpler ways to accomplish the same outcome.

Comment: i want to simulate `dripping water`. it starts dripping from a water source lowering the water source capacity, then it slides on the terrain and finally it reaches a `lake` gameObject. At this point the particle dies and raises the `water amount` int in the target.

Comment: this solved partially the problem, but now i don't know how to access the collided object to modify its values (water amount) https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.CollisionModule-maxKillSpeed.html

Comment: please guys, can i have an update on this? The particles collisions are not detected. Could it be because `void OnParticleCollision` is in conflict with the main module `var main = ps.main;`? Maybe i should write another question to show the complete code?

Comment: Sounds like you can edit this question to show us how to reproduce the problem you're having.

Comment: Documentation says "Messages are only sent if you enable Send Collision Messages in the Inspector of the Particle System Collision module". Did you enable that flag?

Comment: yes i did, nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

1. The ps was missing a `render material`. Apparently this prevents the
   collisions to be detected.
2. I activated `Send Collision Messages` in the Collision Module, without that it won't work.

Thanks all.